# ASP NET. MVC. Значение по-умолчанию для свойства модели

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть модель, одно из свойств модели:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ServerLocale), ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateValidationMessage")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(ServerLocale), Name = "DateLabel")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Модели заполняется с View, на View это свойство выводится так:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)</div>
    <div class="controls">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)<br/>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)</div>
</div>
```

Но при первом открытии формы значение в поле выглядит так:

```
01.01.0001
```

Вопрос как сделать, чтобы при первом открытии формы во View проставлялось значение `DateTime.Now.AddMonth(1)` ???

```
24.01.2017
```

Важно, чтобы данное значение выставлялось свойству только если модель пустая(пользователь в первый раз открыл форму, либо сделал рефреш страницы), если пользователь изменил дату в этом поле, то на контроллер должно прийти значение пользователя

Comment: public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddMonth(1);

Comment: @Андрей, точняк)) спасибо, вынеси в ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть три подхода, но в одном из них AddMonths использовать не получится.

**1. Через конструктор**

```
public ClassName()
{
    Date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)
}
```

**2. Автоматическая инициализация свойств**

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
```

**3. Через аннотацию, но тут это работать не будет**

```
[DefaultValue(1)]
public int Something { get; set; }
```